# lexical analyzer identifying all lines of external called txt file code as identifier rather than tokens

Tags: python, lexical-analysis

**I am writing a lexical analyzer that will identify identifiers, operators, integer and datatype from an external txt file code (text) but it is not recognizing it token by token and identifying them rather it is recognizing every line as identifier**

```
[Image is output of python lexical analyzer code][1]

**Python code for a small lexical analyzer**

import re                                 

tokens = []                               
sample_code = open("file.txt", "r")


for word in sample_code:

   
    if re.match("[a-z]", word) or re.match("[A-Z]", word):
        tokens.append(['IDENTIFIER', word])

    
    elif re.match(".[0-9]", word):
        if word[len(word) - 1] == ';': 
            tokens.append(["INTEGER", word[:-1]])
            tokens.append(['END_STATEMENT', ';'])
        else: 
            tokwns.append(["INTEGER", word])
    
    
    elif word in ['str', 'int', 'bool']: 
        tokens.append(['DATATYPE', word])
    
    
    elif word in '*-/+%=':
        tokens.append(['OPERATOR', word])
    
   

print(tokens, '\n')
```

**Output is in screenshot**

****Text (code) in file.txt****

```
#Pythonprogramtofindthefactorialofanumberprovidedbytheuser.
num=7
factorial=1
# starts
ifnum<0:
print("Sorry,factorialdoesnotexistfornegativenumbers")
elifnum==0:
print("Thefactorialof0is1")
else:
foriinrange(1,num+1):
factorial=factorial*i
print("Thefactorialof",num,"is",factorial)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going through each line at a time, when you should be going through one symbol at a time. To read one symbol at a time, first use the `.read` method on your file (where you used `open`) to get it as text, then split it by every line with the `.split` method:

`sample_code = open("file.txt","r").read().split()`

Also there are a few errors in the regex.

If you want to get a series of alphabetic characters use the regex `"[a-zA-Z]+"`.
For a series of numbers, use the regex `"[0-9]+"` (actually, that allows numbers with preceding zeros so you might instead want to use `"([1-9][0-9]*)|0"`).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I put a mistake. It is meant to split without any arguments then you add the spaces back into the file.